# Basis of $W^{1,p}_0\cap L^2$ using $(\lambda_i, v)_{H^s_0} = \mu_i(\lambda_i, v)_{L^2}$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

> Let $p > 1$. Define $\lambda_i$ by the eigenfunctions of the problem
>   $$(\lambda_i, v)_{H^s_0} = \mu_i(\lambda_i, v)_{L^2}\quad\text{for all $v \in H^s_0(\Omega)$},$$ 
>   where $s$ is chosen large enough so that $H^s_0(\Omega) \subset W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$ continuously (this is what is done in page 3 (or 999) of [this](http://user.math.uzh.ch/chipot/171.pdf).)

Is there a nice way to see why the $\lambda_i \in H^s_0(\Omega)$ are smooth, and why they form a basis of $W^{1,p}_0 \cap L^2$ which is orthonormal in $L^2$?

I'm not even sure what the operator defining the eigenvalue problem is.

*Edit*: comments on this thread refer to the old version.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by $\{\lambda_i\}$ being a basis in $V\cap H$?

Comment: @Rafflesiaarnoldii I edited my post to include some more details and a source of the description of the basis, btw I made in a mistake in saying $p \geq 2$, should be $p > 1$. I think maybe "basis" means finite linear combinations are dense in the $V \cap H$.

Comment: Dense with respect to which norm? Also, every notion of basis I know of requires more than the density of linear span.

Comment: @Rafflesiaarnoldii Hmm, presumably it is wrt. both norms. In this case the result follows easily I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $A:H^s_0 \to (H^s_0)^*$ by $\langle Au, v \rangle = (u,v)_{H^s_0}$ and consider the equation $\langle Au, v \rangle = (f,v){L^2}.$

$u$ exists uniquely, and the solution map $T(f) = u$, $T:L^2 \to L^2$ is compact. Then one can apply the Hilbert-Schmidt theorem.